# Uniform convergence of two functions

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

I just need to know if I'm correctly going about determining whether the following functions converge to their pointwise limits uniformly:
\begin{align*}
&(1) f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{\cos(\frac{x}{n}) + n^2x},\ x\in[0,1]\\
&(2) f_n(x) = 3x^{2n},\ x\in[0,1]
\end{align*}

I'm stuck on $(1)$. I know that the limiting function $f$ on $[0,1]$ is $f(x) = 0$, but I'm having difficulty finding a function which converges to $0$ and also bounds $f_n(x)$.

For $(2)$, the limiting function is not continuous, and thus the convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), note that $0<\cos\frac xn\leqslant1$ for $n\geqslant2$, so $$0\leqslant f_n(x)\leqslant\frac{nx}{1+n^2x}<1$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$. Since $$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left\{\frac{nx}{1+n^2x}\right\} = \frac n{1+n^2}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0, $$
it follows that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Huh... that's more or less what I had, but was having trouble finding justification for my steps. Thank you so much!